# website throwing a server error of 500 (Log code : 204) on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

website throwing a server error of 500  (server log : Error code 204) when accessed through my domain though it works perfectly on my development server.

secondly, development server is not communicating with the database. I don't know why but it connects though it doesn't query.

I'm using php. It's still in preview.

EDIT:
This is a sample from app.yaml file

```
- url: /contactus/.*
  script: contactus.php
- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

When I try to go to "/" it perfectly works. but when I try /aboutus/ it throws a 500 server error only in GAE site.

Sample Code

```
define("pageName", "About Us");
require_once("header.php");
?>
<!--HEADER-->
    <section>
    </section>
    <article>
    </article>
<!--FOOTER-->
<?php
require_once("footer.php");
?>
```

ERROR MESSAGE FROM SERVER LOGS

```
 2013-11-11 03:04:00.313

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

W 2013-11-11 03:04:00.313

A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used
```

main.php also has the same code but it works.

Comment: Can you provide stack traces and sample code for these errors?

Comment: Have you found anything on this? I'm having the same issue. I'm able to connect to DB just fine. When I post forms, I get the 204 at first, but upon refreshing, the data is persisted. I'm using Zend Framework for my project... my log looks the same as yours (the warning bit, anyway).

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira no, not yet. I've been searching through issues. Still, I couldn't even find a trail. For your question, I think, I saw something. Zend Framework utilizes cURL which is not supported in GAE. I hope someone will come up with a best solution until then sit back and watch !

Comment: I don't think the problem in having is related to cURL, since a page reload fixes the issue...

Comment: I've also come across this ticket:  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9553 basically no body has been able to narrow down the problem yet... Arrg.